# How to import external .hpp file?

Tags: c++, header, external

i want to achieve this :

I have some definitions in a .h header, for example :

```
#define myVariable 0x01
```

This .h file is placed somewhere on my PC for example in C:\MyProgram, MyProgram.exe is in the same folder. I want to be able to change directly myVariable and **this change would be effective even if i don't recompile the .exe**, like the h file is external to this exe and not internal/compiled in it.

What is the simplest way to achieve this ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This is not how header files work. Really simplified: when you compile your program the lines with #include gets replaced with the actual contents of the header file, it is just copied in. So what's in there is there to stay.

What you need is to read a file with for example [std::ifstream](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/ifstream/) where the file is located somewhere the program is allowed to read it.